# Android launcher activity between registration Screen and default screen

Tags: android, android-intent, registration, homescreen

I'm developing an application where a registration screen is required,

I initially put the registration sreen as the default

```
<activity android:name=".RegistrationActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And after successfully registered I should make the user never see this screen again

My work around was to make a new intent to the main actual screen

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

but what it does is that when I press back I see the registration screen again

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyNewActivity.class)
    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
this.finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:noHistory="true"` in the activity entry for your registration activity in AndroidManifest.xml. That will prevent the activity from being saved on the stack and it wont show up when you press back button.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is make your main page your "LAUNCHER" activity. Then you check if the user is registered. If the user is not registered send them to the Registration Activity. When your user is finished registering finish the activity and refresh the main page when you return.

It's a good idea to keep the history of pages the app has been to, until you learn how to manage the application stack.